# EBS volume shows no mount point

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, aws-cloud9

**UseCase:** Launch an AWS cloud9 environment that has added EBS of 500GB. This environment will be extensively used to build and publish dockers by developers.

---

So I did start an `m.5.large` instance-based environment and attached an EBS volume of 500GB.

```
Attachment information: i-00xxxxxxb53 (aws-cloud9-dev-6f2xxxx3bda8c):/dev/sdf
```

This is my total storage and I do not see 500GB volume.

[image]

On digging further, it looks like the EBS volume is attached but not at the correct mount point.

[image]

EC2 EBS configuration

[image]

---

**Question:** What should be the next step in order to use this EBS volume?

**Question:** What should be done in order to make use attached EBS for docker building?

**Question:** What should be the most efficient instance type for docker building?

Answer (score 2):

1. Tyoe df -hT here you will find the Filesystem type of root if it is xfs or ext4
2. If say root (/) is xfs, run the following command for the 500 GiB Volume
   $ mkfs -t xfs /dev/nvme1n1
   If root (/) is ext4,
   $ mkfs -t ext4 /dev/nvme1n1
3. Create a directory in root say named mount
   $ mkdir /mount
4. Now mount the 500 GiB Volume to /mount
   $ mount /dev/nvme1n1 /mount
5. Now it will be mounted and can viewed in df -hT
6. Also make sure to update the /etc/fstab so mount remains stable if there is a reboot
7. To update first find UUID if 500 GiB EBS Volume
   $ blkid /dev/nvme1n1
   Note down the UUID from the output
8. Now go to /etc/fstab using editor of your choice
   $ vi /etc/fstab
9. There must be an entry already for /, update for mount and save the file, (note replace xfs with ext4 if filesytem is ext4)
   UUID=<Add_UUID_here_without_""> /mount                   xfs     defaults     0 0
10. Now finally run mount command
    $ mount -a

Comment: thanks for the detailed guide really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if its new EBS volume you have to format it manually and then mount it, also manually. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html):

> After you attach an Amazon EBS volume to your instance, it is exposed as a block device. You can **format the volume** with any file system and then **mount** it.

The instruction for doing this in the link above.